# Error in Firebasse"assert.ts:128 Uncaught FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/invalid-api-key)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Why do I have the error that it says invalid API keys?

This is the sample `.env.local`

```
 REACT_APP_apiKey=AI**************JmXMKaFQQQrRzp4Q
  REACT_APP_authDomain=sample-258a7.firebaseapp.com
  REACT_APP_projectId=sample-258a7
  REACT_APP_storageBucket=sample-258a7.appspot.com
  REACT_APP_messagingSendearId=
  REACT_APP_appId=1:1014069435807:web:04390779a92d4e3a4fb1aa
```

In another file:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getAuth, GoogleAuthProvider, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";

project under its own project settings
const firebaseConfig = {

  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_apiKey,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_authDomain,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_projectId,
  storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_storageBucket,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_messagingSenderId,
  appId: process.env.REACT_APP_appId,
};

//Initializing Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

This is the error:

[image]

The Package.json:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your `.env.local` is placed in the root directory, and not in any subfolders like `src` or `public`. Other than that, nothing seems to be wrong with your code. Just to be safe, cross check your API key with firebase.
P.S. There's no need to hide your firebase public API key, its going to be visible in your app to the general public anyway.

Comment: So there's no need to use the `env.local` for the firebase API?

Comment: @Shoppe No, as long as you're using the public API key, and not the Admin API, which gives you more powerful access as admin, you can just put it directly in your code